# Can I remove the game listing without removing the game?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I want to remove some of the games that appear on my Home screen - the ones I don't play very often, like Face Raiders, for example.

I don't want to take them out of the system completely, because sometimes they are neat to play (or to show other people how the AR works, for Face Raiders). I know I can do that by going to System Settings, then to Data Management, and then from there choosing what I want to remove.

I also would like to avoid "hiding them" by moving them to the last few slots, if at all possible.

What if I just want to "hide" them from the Home screen? Is that possible?

Comment: Sounds to me like moving them is your only option. Is this possible on the Wii? I have all of my stuff I don't use often on the last page of my Wii.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to remove or hide the built-in software like Face Raiders or Safety Warning at all.

3DSWare can be deleted, but not hidden. If you delete it, you'll have to re-download it.

For DSiWare, you can move it to your SD card. This will require you to copy it back off the SD card when you want to play it or show it to someone, but you'll at least not have to re-download it.

The new 3DS firmware update, slated for April 25th, adds folder support to the home screen; you'll be able to add everything you don't want to see to a single folder.

Comment: How do I move it to the DS card? Through the Data Management feature?

Comment: Yeah. First Copy, then Delete. However, this won't work for 3DSWare - it's probably already on your SD card, and it will appear on the home screen no matter which storage it is on.

Comment: Nifty. That does help for some things, though :) Pity I can't do anything about the built-ins. :( Guess I can relegate them to the farthest edge, for now. XD

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how you like to organize your Home Screen, you could just move the icons to the very very last few slots. They'll be out of sight and out of mind for the most part, requiring you to scroll all the way to the end in order to see them. To move, just click and hold on an icon until you see it get "picked up", and then you can drag it to where you want it to go.

Comment: Yeah, I know that's an option, but I'd rather just take them out, if I could.